# What kind of emotion does a phrase "lotsa luck" convey?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

In Quentin Tarantino's Pulp Fiction movie the phrase conveys rather sarcastic emotion:

> I'm here to help. If my help's not appreciated, **lotsa luck**, gentlemen.

Can I use *lotsa luck* to convey positive emotion? For example in a phrase

> and **lotsa luck** in the year to come

Comment: I’d probably use “lots o’ luck” instead.

Answer (score 3):

The expression ***[Lots of luck](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Lots+of+luck!)!*** has two main usages:

> 1. (exclamation) Good luck! *Lots of luck in your new job!*
> 2. (exclamation) *You don’t have a chance!; Good luck, you’ll need it!* (Sarcastic.) *Think you stand a chance? Lots of luck!*

(McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions)